# Fisher-Yates shuffle - Java

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I'm programming (***Java***) a puzzle for college:

[image: Puzzle Image].

The puzzle is based on a 3 x 3 bi-dimensional array and in each position of the array I have an item that contains each piece of image of the puzzle.

- My question here is the following:

I've been told to do the random shuffling of the puzzle with the Fisher-Yates algorythm ([Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)), but I'm not getting it; I'm understanding that it just reverses the order of the array's elements, but I have the feeling that I'm not understanding it well.

Any tips on how to implement it to make it shuffle randomly the elements of bi-dimensional the array?

Comment: Just make it a 1D array of 9 elements, and use Collections.shuffle to shuffle it.

Comment: Just a heads up. If you randomize a sliding puzzle like you're suggesting, you can end up with unsolvable puzzles.